# PHP GIF/PNG True Colorize Filter that Preserves Luminosity and Alpha

Tags: php, colors, gd

I've been working on a script for a while now to change the colors of GIF and PNG files that works better than the PHP colorize filter, which doesn't preserve luminosity. I've come up with this, but it doesn't quite work right:

```
$filename = "images/sprites/".$_GET['sprite'].".png";
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    $nim = imagecreate( imagesx($im), imagesy($im) );
    $background = imagecolorallocate($nim, 255, 0, 255);

    $size = getimagesize($filename);

    for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($nim); $y++) {
        for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($nim); $x++) {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
            $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
            $mods = explode("x",$_GET['color']);

            $colors['red']   = ($colors['red'] / 8 + (255 - ((255 - $mods[0] - $colors['red']) * 2))) / 2;
            $colors['green'] = ($colors['red'] / 8 + (255 - ((255 - $mods[1] - $colors['green']) * 2))) / 2;
            $colors['blue']  = ($colors['red'] / 8 + (255 - ((255 - $mods[2] - $colors['blue']) * 2))) / 2;

            $r = $colors['red'];
            $g = $colors['green'];
            $b = $colors['blue'];

            if($r < 0) $r = 0;
            if($g < 0) $g = 0;
            if($b < 0) $b = 0;
            if($r > 255) $r = 255;
            if($g > 255) $g = 255;
            if($b > 255) $b = 255;

            if(!isset($color[$r.$g.$b])) {
                $color[$r.$g.$b] = imagecolorallocate($nim, $r, $g, $b);
            }

            imagesetpixel($nim, $x, $y, $color[$r.$g.$b]);
        }
    }

    imagecolortransparent($nim, 1);
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($nim);
```

Comment: What is the PHP colorize filter and what do you want it to do? Not to forget: What does not work in your current code?

Comment: The current code works, but it's not quite right. It doesn't truly preserve luminosity and it doesn't preserve an alpha channel. PHP Filter: Colorize will change the color, but not preserve luminosity. Here is the page for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want a tinted grayscale. This supports transparency...

http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/duotone_image

Comment: That looks interesting. I uploaded an image to their test and it didn't work. Leaves me worried about it actually working, but I'll see what affect I get.

Comment: Right, so I tried it and that is doing the same thing the PHP Filter 'Colorize' does. It's not preserving the black in the image. It does preserve the white however.

Comment: Okay, try again at http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/duotone_image, but this time set the pcnt flag

Comment: that's close enough. It favors white a bit, but I can compensate.

Answer (score -1):

Try with these functions after `$im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);`

```
imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
```

And use imagecreatetruecolor() :

```
$nim = imagecreatetruecolor ( imagesx($im), imagesy($im) );
```